# Adding ID3 Tags to Non-MP3 Files

Tags: mp3, music, id3

I was wondering if there was a way to add ID3 tags to anything that isn't a .mp3 file.

I commonly write guitar tabs using a program called Guitar Pro, and the output files are in a .gpx format.  It would be really convenient if I could tag the files with artist/song names in an ID3 tag style so I could easily sort and filter them based on these tags.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

If this isn't possible, are there any other things I could try to better sort my library of songs?  I currently just name the files "Artist - Songname.gpx", but then I can only sort by artist and not song name... (or album or anything else for that matter)

Comment: ID3 is a data container that resides at the beginning of an MP3 file, only MP3 is supported (you could consider it an extension of the MP3 standard). In theory, you could add an ID3 container to the beginning of any file, but no file manager or utility is going to use it for anything since it isn't an MP3 file. Also, since you changed the file's layout I would image Guitar Pro would no longer recognize the files as valid any longer either. GPX files are proprietary to Guitar Pro, so to add information into them, Arobas Music would have to implement it in their software.

Comment: Darn... Oh well... I guess I'll just start an excel spreadsheet with the songs and artists of all of the tabs that I have so I can sort it and easily find everything I have tabs for.